# How can I get the below output using DataWeave?

Tags: mule, dataweave

Input:

```
{
    "city":"bob",
    "state":"void",
    "Street":"TPT",
 "location":{
     "city":"void",
     "state":"void"
}
```

o/p

```
{
  "address": {
    "city": "bob",
     "Street":"TPT",
    "location": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Do not use acronyms that could be confusing (example "o/p"). Please be more explicit, for example use "expected output".

Answer (score 1):

One way is to extract the data from the input payload and construct the expected output:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{ 
    address: { 
        city: payload.city,
        Street: payload.Street,
        location: {} 
    } 
}
```

Output for the input in the question:

```json
{
  "address": {
    "city": "bob",
    "Street": "TPT",
    "location": {
      
    }
  }
}
```